# How do I know if a gradle task has inputs and outputs defined?

Tags: gradle

I cannot find any hints in the docs what the inputs and outputs of a task are. I would like to know for example if the test-task can be skipped and when it will be skipped.

Comment: When do you want to skip or expect that it can be skipped ? It can be skipped by passing the appropriate key to gradle if that's what you want

Comment: I would like to know when the task is considered as UP-TO-DATE. Here's a picture that shows the inputs of the JavaCompile Task: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this using the built-in features of the `gradlew` command, but it's possible using the Gradle runtime API if you're happy to add a bit of code to your `build.gradle` file. You could add the logic for grabbing a task and printing its inputs and outputs into a `gradle.projectsEvaluated` block, or in a task that you run specifically for this purpose.

For instance, this code (in a Groovy `build.gradle` file) defines a task `printInputsAndOutputs` that will print the inputs and outputs of the `compileJava` task:

```
tasks.register("printInputsAndOutputs") {
    doLast {
        Task task = tasks.getByPath(":app:compileJava")

        TaskInputs inputs = task.inputs
        println("compileJava has inputs? ${inputs.hasInputs}")
        println("compileJava input files: ${inputs.files.asPath}")
        println("compileJava hasSourceFiles? ${inputs.hasSourceFiles}")
        println("compileJava input source files: ${inputs.sourceFiles.asPath}")
        println()

        TaskOutputs outputs = task.outputs
        println("compileJava has output? ${outputs.hasOutput}")
        println("compileJava output files: ${outputs.files.asPath}")
    }
}
```

Here's the output I see when I run this locally in my newly `gradle init`ed project:

```
$ ./gradlew printInputs

> Task :app:printInputsAndOutputs
compileJava has inputs? true
compileJava input files: /home/mark/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-text/1.9/ba6ac8c2807490944a0a27f6f8e68fb5ed2e80e2/commons-text-1.9.jar:/home/mark/demo/utilities/build/classes/java/main:/home/mark/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.11/68e9a6adf7cf8eb7e9d31bbc554c7c75eeaac568/commons-lang3-3.11.jar:/home/mark/demo/list/build/classes/java/main:/home/mark/demo/app/src/main/java/demo/app/MessageUtils.java:/home/mark/demo/app/src/main/java/demo/app/App.java
compileJava hasSourceFiles? true
compileJava input source files: /home/mark/demo/app/src/main/java/demo/app/MessageUtils.java:/home/mark/demo/app/src/main/java/demo/app/App.java

compileJava has output? true
compileJava output files: /home/mark/demo/app/build/classes/java/main:/home/mark/demo/app/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main:/home/mark/demo/app/build/generated/sources/headers/java/main:/home/mark/demo/app/build/tmp/compileJava/previous-compilation-data.bin

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 351ms
10 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 9 up-to-date
```

Naturally, tweak as you see fit to get a different task, slightly different information, or perhaps to take a task name via a `-P` parameter if you want a permanent, reusable task for doing this kind of introspection.

Answer (score 0):

For example, your `compile` task input is the source code. If the source code hasn't changed since the last compile, then it will check the output to make sure you haven't blown away your class files generated by the compiler. If the input and output is unchanged, it considers the task `UP-TO-DATE` and doesn't execute that task.

If you want to know the specific input and output for each task, you'd need to look at the docs. However, there really is not much practical value in it. As the base input to series of tasks run by `gradle test` there is only the `main` source code and the `test` source code. And all other inputs are derived from it.

So if you've changed 0 code and do a rerun every subtask of the `test` task will be `UP-TO-DATE`. If you change only the test code, then all tasks will be `UP-TO-DATE` except for `compileTestJava`. If you change both the `test` and `main` code all tasks will be rerun.

Comment: I would like to know the specific input and output for each task and I couldn't find it in the docs. Just give me an example/link to the docs of a task with inputs and outputs.

Comment: *"If you want to know the specific input and output for each task, you'd need to look at the docs. However, there really is not much practical value in it."* Of course there is practical value in it - it lets you check whether your tasks have their inputs defined properly, and debug what's going on if you've discovered they don't.

Comment: @MarkAmery exactly. Thank you. In my case I may have additional files in the test folder and I want to know if they're part of the input, e.g. an dbunit xml file. Imagine pushing breaking changes, but the CI system picks test results from cache.